# Python: Best practice for raising and/or inspecting exceptions

Tags: python, exception, stack-trace

I have a setup in my Python code resembling this:

```
def a():
    raise MyUserDefinedException()

def b():
    a()

def c():
    a()

def d():
    b()
    c()

def main():
    try:
        d()
    except MyUserDefinedException as e
        print e
```

However, I want different things printed out depending on whether the exception happened during b() or during c().  For various design reasons, I want all printing to be handled in main().

What would be the best way to go about this?  Should I have a try-catch block in b() and c() that catches MyUserDefinedException as raises a new exception specific to that method or is there a **clean** way of inspecting the trace?

Comment: If exceptions going through `b` should have a different result, it is `b`'s responsibility to be coded to produce that different result.

Comment: You can get the traceback with `sys.exc_info`.  But if you want to do different things depending on which function raised the exception, then you should probably have those different functions raise different exceptions, or have `d` use two `try` blocks and raise a different exception for each call.  The question is, is the difference because exceptions in `b` and `c` should be handled differently, always, or just because `d` should raise different exceptions in the two cases?